# vb.net DatagridView Filtering on modified datasource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter

I have a DatagridView (DatagridView1) that I populate from a database with:

```
Me.DatagridView1.DataSource = DataTable1
```

I am then adding 2 columns (Icon & Status) to my dataGridView one with an icon and one with a description depending on the values retrieve from DataTable1 (typically, error, warning etc)

I have then a drop down (DropDown1) with values 'All', 'Error', 'Warning', etc

I want to filter my DataGridView base on the selected value in the DropDown1.
e.g. If 'Error' selected I will only show lines with 'Error' in the Status column.
I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDown1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    dt = TryCast(DatagridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Status Like '*" & Trim(Me.DropDown1.Text.ToString) & "*'")
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I have 2 issues:

1. I have an error saying he does not recognize Column Status (which is normal, as when debugging, I see that DataGridView1.DataSource only contains the original data from the Database and not the columns I have added) - How do I retrieve all my columns?
2. How do I remove all filters (when All is selected)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have the solution.
First thanks to theBurger dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "" does clear the filter.

About data source the issue was I was adding the column directly to the grid instead of adding them into my datatable and then refresh the datagrid.

Comment: If you think the answer posted by a user is useful, it's better to upvote the answer. It means the answer is useful. It makes the post more usful for future readers.

Comment: I'm not the**Burger** :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should clear your filter

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = ""
```

To retrieve your columns you have to access them from the DataGridView itself

```
DatagridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).value
```